# OAuthCommunicationException exception in yahoo integration of android.

Tags: android, yahoo

Hello Friends,
             After successfully get consumer-key and consumer secret from yahoo. then got the request token and authentication verifier but geting access token shows 404 i.e OAuthCommunicationException exception.

String CALLBACK_URL = "yahooapi://callback";

```
   @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  myProvider.retrieveAccessToken(myConsumer, verifier);    ////showing error here
  return null;
     }


    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:host="callback"
       android:scheme="yahooapi" >
      </data>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: please provide the solutions..thanks